# Is there event of "controller created" in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need to catch `$scope` creation for all `controllers` throughout the whole `module` to get and maintain currently created `$scope`'s information such as `$id` or any other.
My working code is:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.CurrentScopeID = $scope.$id;
    // ...
})
```

I want to maximally centralize this logic and need to solve this problem if it is possible.

Comment: don't do this.  using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern, and trying to set a variable on each controller to the same value is redundant an error prone.  If you have a singular value that you need to access between multiple controllers, use a service, which is a singleton already, and designed exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a init function to your controllers:

```
var init = function(){
$rootScope.CurrentScopeID = $scope.$id;
}

init();
```

This code will run once the controller is loaded up!

Comment: Yes of course it is solution some extent but not entirely because i must call this method in all controller. Need to catch controller created moment like C# events if it is possible if not your answer will be perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular version 1.5+, there is lifecycle hooks which help to run code in special moments of time. In your case you need `$onInit()` phase.

Here - [Lifecycle hooks in Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) you can find more information about that.